# Open class files in VSCode and add a debug breakpoint anywhere

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to add a breakpoint in a class library. I must first open the target library class file (decompiled), and add a breakpoint later.

[image]

But it looks like I can view the class library **only** while debugging the java application. How can I **goto** specific library class file in vscode?

Comment: You can press `Ctrl + T` (on Windows), which is the shortcut for symbol search. Then, you just type `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` in the input box and you should be able to find it.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments above, this allows you to search all classes including source files and library classes.